# Where can I store variables in Java for later use in html or jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I try to prepare some data from MySQL in a Java String array in a servlet, but after clicking another page(after a request and a respond) this data is lost in the array and it gives NullPointerException. Is there a way I can save data in a Java object that will maintain after several HTML or JSP pages have been changed?

Comment: Store it in the Session ?

Comment: Take a look at sessions.

Comment: You would have probably stored it in request scope. Hence the data is lost after the request is served. As @Berger said, you may have to store it in either session or application scope, depending on its visibility